# How to set QTextEdit to only start editing on mouse click/release?

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

I tried `setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);` but the cursor starts flashing and gets focus as soon as the mouse is pressed on it.

Is there a way to change it to mouse click?

I'm using Qt 4.6.3 on a touch screen device.

When `QTextEdit` gets the focus, then the `KineticScroller` stops working.

**What I want to achieve:**

1) On mouse press event `QTextEdit` does nothing.
2) On mouse release event, if the release is within the `rect()` of `QTextEdit`, then it gets focus and start editing.
3) If not in `rect()` don't do anything.

I know how to acheive 2) and 3) by rewriting `mousePressEvent()` and `mouseReleaseEvent()` but I have no I idea how not to let it get focus on mouse press.

Can someone share some thoughts on why `setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);` doesn't do this for me?

Comment: Do you get the desired behavior when using the mouse instead of a touch screen?

Comment: @cdonts I guess the answer is no, because `QTextEdit` has very poor support of touch event (so are a lot of other QWidgets in Qt4), I need make a event filter for it to convert touch event to mouse event before I can do anything with it. This post is assuming all touch press/release events are converted to mouse press/release events by this filter first.

Comment: Well, Qt should automatically convert touch events to mouse events. If you created your own filter then that might be the reason why `setFocusPolicy` doesn't work.

Comment: @cdonts but as I mentioned, this mechanism is poorly implemented in Qt 4.6.3. I have no problem with `QPushButton` and most others, but `QTextEdit` and `QListView` are two counter examples I have came across. That's why I wrote my own filter.

Comment: Ok. Why don't you just ignore the mouse press event?